# Sibling components with router outlet

Tags: angular

I ve started with angular and i just can't get my head around the Router, here is my problem ....

Lets assume i have a application structure like so ...

[image: App structure]

Now in Feature 'C' Component html is as follows ...

```
<feature-d-component></feature-d-component>
<feature-e-component></feature-e-component>
```

Each of those have an router-outlet, ie feature 'D' component and Feature 'E' component have the same html as follows

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Can this be implemented? 
And if it can, could you give an route configuration example and also a example how would one route to this with routerLink?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, what you described can be accomplished by using **named router outlets**.

For the purpose of demonstrating this I used the example app you provided in your image.

Example router config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{   
    path: 'featureA',
      component: FeatureAComponent,
    }, {
      path: 'featureB',
      component: FeatureBComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'featureC',
      component: FeatureCComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'childE', component: EChildComponent, outlet: 'routeE' },
        { path: 'childD', component: DChildComponent, outlet: 'routeD' }
      ]
    },  { 
      path: '', 
      redirectTo: '/featureA',
      pathMatch: 'full'
   },
];
```

Your app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <a [routerLink]="['featureA']">feature-a</a>
  <br>
  <a [routerLink]="['featureB']">feature-b</a>
  <br>
  <a [routerLink]="['featureC']">feature-c</a>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

and your feature C component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'feature-c',
  template: `
    <h1>Showing feature-c component</h1>
    <feature-d></feature-d>
    <feature-e></feature-e>
  `,
})
export class FeatureCComponent {
}
```

Now getting into the named router outlets. You mentioned you wanted to use routerLink, so that is the method I used in the demonstration. See feature-d:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'feature-d',
  template: `
    <h3>feature-d</h3>
    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { routeD: ['childD'] } }]">Show child D</a>
    <router-outlet name="routeD"></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class FeatureDComponent {
}
```

For simplicity Feature-e is implemented the same as feature-d.
Attached is a live StackBlitz demo that I created so you can see it in action and play around with it to your liking.

Be warned I didn't do any beautification to the StackBlitz, so it looks pretty basic, but it gets the job done!

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-etb4cb)

Comment: Here is a link to the Angular guide section on named route outlets: https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets, in case there is any value there. :)

Comment: Since the external links can become invalid in the future, it is recommended to give more details and/or to show an example in the answer.

Comment: Please add the relevant sections of your linked resource to the answer

Comment: I will update the answer when I get home in a little while with more info and code. Thanks @ConnorsFan for the suggestion.

Comment: Thx, for the replay, i've went throu quite a bit of tutorial on the subject of routing and can't seem to grasp the concept. I would really appreciate a route config for the given example. I think that would go a long way for me. Also how would a routerLink look like if i wanted to change only first part of the url and keep the rest, and consequently change the view in one of the named outlets

Comment: Updated the answer, I do hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thx, this was really helpful. Could you also add how would the route config look if i wanted to lazy load modules feature D and feature E, and a route config of one of those two modules ?

Comment: You're only suppose to ask one question per post on SO, so each post has one clear concise answer. If you post another question though I'd be happy to discuss/show it in that post.